# How to plot the data points in Excel using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have been trying to use data to create a graph in an excel sheet. My data source is the same workbook. Data is in sheet 1 and I want to create the graph in sheet 2. I have read through almost all the StackOverflow threads and other web resources. I can't seem to find where I have gone wrong. The graph does not show anything but the axes correctly scaled.

I want to plot column A(X Axis) against B, C, D and E in four different line/bar charts. I use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace.

This is the code snippet.

```
Worksheet sheet2 = workBook.Worksheets[2];
ChartObjects chart = sheet2.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
ChartObject[] chartObj = {chart.Add(10, 10, 550, 300), chart.Add(580, 10, 550, 300), chart.Add(10, 350, 550, 300), chart.Add(580, 350, 550, 300) };
int[,] rangeVal = { { 0, 400 }, { 0, 100 }, { 0, 300 }, { 0, 5 } };
for (int col = 2; col <= colsCount; col++)
{
     Chart myChart = chartObj[col-2].Chart;
     chartObj[col - 2].Select();

     myChart.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlChartType.xlLine;
     SeriesCollection seriesCollection = myChart.SeriesCollection();

     Series series1 = seriesCollection.NewSeries();
     series1.Name = sheet1.Cells[1,col].Value.ToString();
     series1.XValues = sheet1.get_Range("A2","A" + (rowsCount + 1).ToString());
     series1.Values = sheet1.get_Range((char)((int)'A' + col - 1) + "2", (char)((int)'A' + col - 1) + (rowsCount + 1).ToString());

     series1.ChartType = XlChartType.xlLine;
     myChart.PlotBy = XlRowCol.xlRows;
     myChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue).MinimumScale = rangeVal[col-2,0];
     myChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue).MaximumScale = rangeVal[col-2,1];
     //myChart.SetSourceData(sheet1.get_Range((char)((int)'A' + col - 1) + "2", (char)((int)'A' + col - 1) + (rowsCount + 1).ToString()));
}
```

This is the screenshot of the graph with commented `SetSourceData` statement:
[image: GraphWithoutSetSourceData]

This is the screenshot of the graph with `SetSourceData` enabled:
[image: GraphWithSetSourceData]

And my data set does not have any zero values.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is looking for answers. This was my scenario:

I read data from MySQL into a DataTable and the problem was how I saved the data in sheet1. I stored them as string values. And that's why the part where I read the data from sheet1 doesn't convert string values to numerical values. It simply takes it as 0.

The code above works perfectly otherwise.

Silly mistake! :)